# AppSpector not run on Simulater IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I use appspector to remote debug my app.

I have config and run successfully on real device. It works fine both on emulator, but on simulator it doesn't work.

Xcode gives the following error:

```
Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/Users/tranhieu/StudioProjects/mochian_flutter/ios/Pods/AppSpectorSDK/AppSpectorSDK.framework/AppSpectorSDK' for architecture arm64
```

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to fix it as follows:
1.

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

2. Inside Build Setting> Excluded Architectures > debug: fill arm64

But all is not working